# How to assign returning value from Postgresql insert to a variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert one record into Postgresql, get inserted id, and use it in following 4 other inserts. I can't get it to work. This is what I have so far:

```
do $$
declare
    gameId integer
begin
    INSERT INTO public."Games" ("SeasonId", "StartTime", "GameStatusId", "AwayTeamId", "HomeTeamId", "IsVenueNeutral", "ModifiedOn", "Comment") 
    values(15, '2021-05-20 22:30:00.000', 1, 11, 12, false, '2022-01-29 20:20:00.000', 'Test')
    returning "GameId" into gameId ;

    INSERT INTO public."GameScores" ("GameId", "Period", "AwayScore", "HomeScore")
    VALUES(gameId , 1, 10, 10),
    VALUES(gameId , 2, 10, 10),
    VALUES(gameId , 3, 10, 10),
    VALUES(gameId , 4, 10, 10);
end $$;
```

I'm not even sure if I need to wrap it in `do` and `end`. All I want to is to generate a script to insert a bunch of data in one go. In some cases I need to reuse id of previously inserted record.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use to use another variable `g_id` instead of `gameId` because there is another `GameId` column from your table, then the `insert into` may be like this.

```
do $$
declare
    g_id integer;
begin
    INSERT INTO public."Games" ("SeasonId", "StartTime", "GameStatusId", "AwayTeamId", "HomeTeamId", "IsVenueNeutral", "ModifiedOn", "Comment") 
    values(15, '2021-05-20 22:30:00.000', 1, 11, 12, false, '2022-01-29 20:20:00.000', 'Test')
    returning "GameId" into g_id ;

    INSERT INTO public."GameScores" ("GameId", "Period", "AwayScore", "HomeScore")
    VALUES(g_id , 1, 10, 10),
    (g_id , 2, 10, 10),
    (g_id , 3, 10, 10),
    (g_id , 4, 10, 10);
end $$;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=755afa7754ed27f67687f1407ad30871)

Another way can try to use CTE to do that, then get the `GameId` from cte then do another `insert into`

```
WITH rows AS (
    INSERT INTO public."Games" ("SeasonId", "StartTime", "GameStatusId", "AwayTeamId", "HomeTeamId", "IsVenueNeutral", "ModifiedOn", "Comment") 
    values(15, '2021-05-20 22:30:00.000', 1, 11, 12, false, '2022-01-29 20:20:00.000', 'Test')
    returning "GameId"
)
INSERT INTO public."GameScores" ("GameId", "Period", "AwayScore", "HomeScore")
SELECT GameId,Period, AwayScore,HomeScore
FROM rows r CROSS JOIN 
LATERAL (VALUES
(1, 10, 10),
(2, 10, 10),
(3, 10, 10),
(4, 10, 10)
) s(Period, AwayScore,HomeScore);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=28812f634b771c9fdce4e5db6aec65d5)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it works (although, I had to put column names in to double quotes, which is annoying). I wish there was an easier way to do it, but if it works, it works.

Comment: @IshThomas Ok I see I had edited my answer hope that can help you.

Comment: With "do end" option, I'm getting this error: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "begin"
  Position: 24
  Where: invalid type name "integer`

Comment: I've tried first `insert` without `into`, it worked. I tried `insert` into `GameScores` but without `g_id` and it worked as well. So, I don't know how to declare a variable, or `into` doesn't work.

Comment: I guess there is another issue with your query because it work on sqlfiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=755afa7754ed27f67687f1407ad30871

Comment: I'm using Dbeaver, does it even matter?